# how do extension methods like .ToList() and .Reverse() look behind the covers?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

i use lots of extension methods like `.ToList()` and `.Reverse()` etc without really thinking about what really happens under the covers when i use them. I've been searching on google to find out what exactly these methods do, but i can't seem to find them anywhere. When i use a `.toList()` in visual studio and i click on "`Go to definition`" all i see is

```
         // Summary:
        //     Creates a System.Collections.Generic.List<T> from an System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   source:
        //     The System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> to create a System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
        //     from.
        //
       ...etc
```

im trying to find out what's going on inside the (for instance) `.Reverse();` method. Does it use a stack, does it simply do something like this ... ?

```
public static List<string> Reverse(List<string> oldList)
{
List<string> newList = new List<string>();    
for (int i = oldList.Count-1; i >= 0; i --)
    {
    newList.Add(oldList[i]);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Note: i can't imagine it'd actually be something like this, but just to clarify my question.

**Is there any site/book/whatever that i can check out that shows what exactly these methods do ?**

Comment: I have a whole blog series reimplementing LINQ to Objects from scratch. It doesn't necessarily give the *same* implementation, but then that could change between framework versions anyway... http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure Visual Studio to load the source code of .Net Framework from Microsoft source servers, when you click 'Go to Definition'. Here are some instructions: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/downloadsetup.aspx

Note that you don't have to download the big package, just setting up the options is enough.

Here is the source code of `ToList`:

```
    public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) { 
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        return new List<TSource>(source); 
    }
```

And here is the source code of `Reverse`:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Reverse<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source"); 
        return ReverseIterator<TSource>(source);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TSource> ReverseIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source) { 
        Buffer<TSource> buffer = new Buffer<TSource>(source);
        for (int i = buffer.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) yield return buffer.items[i]; 
    }
```

Comment: Note that for `Reverse` much of the interesting aspect of it's code is all in the `Buffer` class, which isn't shown.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, I thought it was just a vanilla List or Array. I encourage op to dig into it herself though, to make sure the settings are correct :)

Answer (score 2):

`.ToList()` does:

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

And `.Reverse()` calls [Array.Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z78xtwts.aspx) on the underlying array of the list.

I found it out by decompilation with Reflector, but you could also take a look at [the .NET source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Jon Skeet (if he doesn't beat me to it here) has written a wonderful (and long) [series of blog posts](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts/) in which he (more or less) re-implements Linq to Objects.  You can see his implementations (which are generally the same or similar to the libraries implementations) of all of the methods, including those you have listed here.

In the case of `Reverse`, one primary difference between your implementation and the Library (and Jon's) implementation is differed execution.  `Reverse` doesn't enumerate any of the elements of the `IEnumerable` that is passed in until it has to (in this case, it's when the first item is requested).  I leave the more in depth analysis of the consequences of that difference to that blog series.

Comment: The best thing about Jon's effort is the detail to which he goes to describe WHY implementations are the way they are.

Comment: In my understanding the magic `Buffer` class enumerates the `source` immediately when constructed. And it is constructed immediately when you call `Reverse()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @YuxiuLi Yes, you are.  `ReverseIterator` (the helper method) is in an iterator block, it's not a normal method.  It has a `yield return` statement.  This is what generates the code that causes deferred execution.

Comment: Didn't know execution of iterators are deferred to enumeration time. Thanks :)

Comment: [New link](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-1-introduction/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/features/index.html) to browse the code.

Answer (score 1):

An extension method is just a plain old static method, but the object whose class you're extending is passed as a parameter to it. So lets say we want to extend the built-in class int to include a `toString()` method (yes, I know, it already has one). The syntax looks like this:

```
public static string toString(this int myInt)
{
     return (string)myInt;
}
```

Notice the `this` keyword for the parameter. That tells the compiler that this is an extension method.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but shouldnt it be public static string toString then?

Comment: @JaneDoe yeah, it should. Forgot to put it in there when I wrote it